# How to utilize Word Spell Checker via VSTO?

Tags: .net, ms-word, vsto, spell-checking

Currently I am running a research project to process English text. The text data is quite noisy and contains many spelling and grammatical errors.

I know MS Word can automatically highlight these errors in their own MS Word application.

My question is, can I programmatically call their spelling check engine (possibly via VSTO), to get the errors as well as the correction suggestion for any given text strings? without using any MS Word GUI.

Ideally, I am asking for function:

> List< Errors> RunSpellChecking(String text)

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a sample code [here](http://codeidol.com/community/dotnet/working-with-the-application-object/8645/)

Check on this MSDN as well

[GetSpellingSuggestions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/microsoft.office.interop.word._application.getspellingsuggestions.aspx)

[CheckSpelling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.checkspelling%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

why word? can you use spellchek library like http://nhunspell.sourceforge.net/